# please help me for customizing my django admin pannel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools, django-admin-actions

i should add this tables in my admin class in django please help me
[image: i target image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are trying to get the Group model or just Groups in the User model.

To add Group in Admin you can do like this in `admin.py` file:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

User = get_user_model()

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Group)
```

Or if you just want to add extra properties in `User` you can do like this in your `UserAdmin` class:

```py
fieldsets = (
    # ...
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('groups', 'user_permissions')}),
)
```

and Update `admin.site.register(User)` line with

```py
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```